# cannot schedule kubernetes pods with request for nvidia.com/gpu

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, nvidia

i have been able to get kubernetes to recognise my gpus on my nodes:

```
$ kubectl get node MY_NODE -o yaml
...
allocatable:
  cpu: "48"
  ephemeral-storage: "15098429006"
  hugepages-1Gi: "0" 
  hugepages-2Mi: "0"
   memory: 263756344Ki
  nvidia.com/gpu: "8"
  pods: "110"
capacity:
  cpu: "48"
  ephemeral-storage: 16382844Ki
  hugepages-1Gi: "0"
  hugepages-2Mi: "0"
  memory: 263858744Ki
  nvidia.com/gpu: "8"
  pods: "110"
...
```

and i spin up a pod with

```
Limits:
  cpu:             2
  memory:          2147483648
  nvidia.com/gpu:  1
Requests:
  cpu:             500m
  memory:          536870912
  nvidia.com/gpu:  1
```

However, the pod stays in PENDING with:

```
Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu.
```

Am i spec'ing the resources correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed NVIDIA plugin in K8S?

```
kubectl create -f nvidia.io/device-plugin.yml
```

Some devices are too old and cannot be healthchecked.So this option must be disabled:

```
containers:
      - image: nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:1.9
        name: nvidia-device-plugin-ctr
        env:
        - name: DP_DISABLE_HEALTHCHECKS
          value: "xids"
```

Take a look at:

- Device plugin: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/device-plugins/
- NVIDIA github: https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin

Comment: yes, that's how i got the `allocatable` and `capacity` `nvidia.com/gpu` values to show up.